# this.Close(); doesn't work in window wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

In wpf, window I am calling window forms. Before calling that I just want to close that window. Here is my code.

```
  public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
  {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnIntroClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            PdfReader form = new PdfReader(1);

            form.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();

        }
   }
```

No error, but form is not closing.
And in window form also, `this.Close()` in not working

```
 public partial class PdfReader : Form
 {
        public PdfReader(int page_num)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var executingFolder = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            var dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(executingFolder, "BiodermaProduct.pdf");
            axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(dbPath);

            axAcroPDF1.setCurrentPage(page_num);
        }

        private void PdfReader_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
           this.Opacity = 0;
           MainWindow w = new MainWindow();
           w.ShowDialog();

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will close when you close your `PdfReader form`. `Form.ShowDialog` returns only when the form is closed. So `this.Close()` is not called until `ShowDialog` finishes.
What you can do is set `this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden` before calling `form.ShowDialog();`

Comment: ... or don't use `ShowDialog` in the first place. The parent form is dying anyway, so it's not going to make any difference. Just use `Show`.

Comment: The form may need to be modal for the rest of the application

Comment: Thanks !! this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Important detail that we need to bear in mind when we deal with windows closure and other UI operation: **we need to execute it in UI thread only**.
This is exactly that happened in my case.

I raised an event from the server and when it happened I raised another event through custom *Event Aggregator* to close the second Window that is opened (without shutting down the application). 
However it didn't happen without an error or visible reason. My window was still opened.
Nevertheless, when I enabled "Common Language Runtime exception" through visual studio settings:

[image]

I caught the exception: "*Full Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
   at System.Windows.Window.Close()..........*"

Consequently, instead of this:

```
  ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>().GetEvent<ServerDisconnectedEvent>()
         .Subscribe(e => Close());
```

Run this:

```
        ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>().GetEvent<ServerDisconnectedEvent>()
            .Subscribe(e => Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(Close)));
```

I hope this will safe time for someone like me :)

Answer (score 1):

When You use `Window.ShowDialog()`, it calls new Window modally, meaning you cannot go to the parent form.

The `Window.Show()` function shows the form in a non modal form. This means that you can click on the parent form.

However, this code will close your application as **[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx)**(thanks to @Empereur Aiman):

> A ShutdownMode of OnMainWindowClose causes Windows Presentation
>   Foundation (WPF) to implicitly call Shutdown when the MainWindow
>   closes, **even if other windows are currently open**.

And you should set your `ShutdownMode` to `OnLastWindowClose` as [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If you set ShutdownMode to OnLastWindowClose, Windows Presentation
>   Foundation (WPF) implicitly calls Shutdown when the last window in an
>   application closes, even if any currently instantiated windows are set
>   as the main window (see MainWindow).

Just reorder your call of ShowDialog():

```
PdfReader form = new PdfReader(1);
this.Close();
form.ShowDialog();
```

or:

```
PdfReader form = new PdfReader(1);
form.Show();
this.Close();
```

and set `ShutdownMode="OnLastWindowClose"` at `App.xaml` file of your application:

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
    ShutdownMode="OnLastWindowClose"
    >
</Application>
```

**You code is:**

```
PdfReader form = new PdfReader(1);
form.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

It means [`CLR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) executes **modally** your new `PdfReader` window. That is, execution of your program goes to `PdfReader` window. And only **after closing** PdfReader window, `CLR` executes your next row:

```
this.Close();
```

and your `MainWindow()` will be closed.

Comment: Well, this will end the program I guess before `win.ShowDialog` is called.

Comment: Unless `Application.ShutdownMode` is not on `OnMainWindowClose`, which is the default, the program will end when `this.Close();` is called (Because there is no other windows open).

Answer (score 1):

If you read [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you'll see that `ShowDialog` only returns when said window is closed. This means your code is blocked on that line until the window is closed. You have to close your current window first, then `ShowDialog`.

```
    private void BtnIntroClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PdfReader form = new PdfReader(1);
        this.Close();
        form.ShowDialog();

    }
```

Note that `Show` does not work in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order between `this.Close();` & `form.ShowDialog();` and it will work well

Try this code:

```
private void BtnIntroClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

  PdfReader form = new PdfReader(1);
  this.Close();
  form.ShowDialog();
 }
```